# Handle byte* pointer and convert it to something else

Tags: c#, arrays, image, pointers, uwp

I have a probably stupid question, but I can't figure out how to solve it by myself.

I have obtained a byte* pointer from a SoftwareBitmap's pixel data, then I edited some pixel data… and now I don't know how to use that byte* pointer.

How can I convert it to a IBuffer, for example, in order to use it to create a new SoftwareBitmap?
Is there an easier way to create a new Bitmap?

Here's the code, by the way, even thought it shouldn't be of any help:

1. DLL Import

   ```
   [ComImport]
   [Guid("5b0d3235-4dba-4d44-865e-8f1d0e4fd04d")]
   [InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIUnknown)]
   unsafe interface IMemoryBufferByteAccess
   {
       void GetBuffer(out byte* buffer, out uint capacity);
   }
   ```
2. Main function

   ```
   private unsafe SoftwareBitmap PixelateImage(SoftwareBitmap bitmap, Boolean AlphaEnabled)
   {
       using (var buffer = bitmap.LockBuffer(BitmapBufferAccessMode.Read))
       {
           using (var reference = buffer.CreateReference())
           {
               ((IMemoryBufferByteAccess)reference).GetBuffer(out byte* data, out uint capacity);

               // Doing things with data[int index] bytes…

               SoftwareBitmap bmp = new SoftwareBitmap(bitmap.BitmapPixelFormat, bitmap.PixelWidth, bitmap.PixelHeight, bitmap.BitmapAlphaMode);

               // How to use byte* data else?
               // bmp.CopyFromBuffer(IBuffer)  <=== How to get an IBuffer from byte*?

               return bmp;
           }
       }
   }
   ```

Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The byte pointer can be seen as an unsafe array of byte in the .NET world, so first we would need to do this marshal:

```
var safearray = new byte[capacity];
Marshal.Copy((IntPtr)data, safearray, 0, capacity);
```

(the other alternative is an unsafe cast to avoid the copy, if performance is an issue, ie. if you're dealing with many and/or large bitmaps).

Then we can simply write:

```
IBuffer safebuffer = safearray.AsBuffer();
```

which is an extension from the `System.Runtime.InteropServices.WindowsRuntime` namespace.

Comment: Yes, performance is very important, as I need to work with even 20 mpx images… so what's the alternative?  Thanks